# Exporting Night Lights data as per the given shapefile in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to GIS and Google Earth Engine Platform. I am trying to get the night lights for all counties in a country. I have uploaded the shapefile as an asset to the platform. I want to export the avg_vis for the region as per the boundaries defined by the shapefile for each county. I want to export them hopefully as an excel file. Additionally, I want to do this for 35 years for which data is available. The code I have till now is:

```
var shp = ee.FeatureCollection(table);
var dataset=imageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.date('1992-01-01', '1992-12-31')).map(function(image){return image.clip(shp)});
var nighttimeLights = dataset.select('avg_vis');
var nighttimeLightsVis = {
  min: 3.0,
  max: 63.0,
};
var nl=dataset.reduceRegions({ 


collection: shp,
  reducer:ee.Reducer.mean()

});

    print(table.size());
    Map.addLayer(nighttimeLights, nighttimeLightsVis, 'Nighttime Lights');
```

imageCollection is the DMSP Nightlights Image Collection and table is the shapefile that I have. I am getting an error that reduceRegions function does not exist. I understand that it maybe happening due to casting but how do I resolve it and also, how to export it subsequently?

Answer (score 1):

Reduceregions should be applied to single images, instead of an image collection. Therefore, you shoul dmap over the image collection:

```
// map over the collection (reduceRegions works on single imagery)
var nl = nighttimeLights.map(function(image){
  var year = image.date().format('YYYY');
  var feats = image.reduceRegions({ 
    collection: shp,
    reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 1000 // scale to do reduce region, depends on the accuracy/location on earth 
  })
  // return a feature collection 
  .map(function(feat){
    return ee.Feature(ee.Feature(feat).set('year', year)
            // copy the image properties
            .copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames()));
  });
  return feats;
  // flatte nthe feature collection of collection
}).flatten();
```

Then export as follows:

```
// export
Export.table.toDrive(nl, 'nightlight', 'SPECIFYFOLDER', '', 'CSV');
print(nl)
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3f4eeb0af70311dd331bb3a3ee351abe)
note that I used a random made geometry for testing this. You should use your own, which you should share if it throws an error.